# Extracting an audio clip from a specific sample position using MoviePy in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I need to extract a specific audio clip from an audio file based on sample positions, not time intervals. I'm using MoviePy in Python for video and audio editing.

I have the audio file and the start and end sample positions that define the portion I want to extract. However, I'm unsure how to accomplish this using MoviePy.

I've explored the AudioFileClip class in MoviePy, but it seems to be primarily focused on time-based extraction rather than sample-based extraction.

Is there a way to extract an audio clip from a specific sample position using MoviePy or any other Python library that integrates well with MoviePy?

I would appreciate any guidance or code examples that demonstrate how to achieve this audio extraction based on sample positions using MoviePy or any other suitable library.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: I prefer using `moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools.ffmpeg_extract_audio`